# crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0.msi' in item cannot be located on disk error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment, crystal-reports-2010

i am deploying my windows desktop application in visual studio 2010 having reporting in crystal reports during build of my setup project i get the error

**"The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0.msi' in item 'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework 4.0' can not be located on disk.**

i search for this error and get this help

•Find a product.xml file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\

•Open the product.xml file in Notepad (or any text editor)

•Under the  section, find 2 URLs that point to the 2 deployment packages

•Copy each URL into your web browser and manually download the packages

•Once the packages are downloaded, copy them to the same folder as the product.xml file
 •Build and publish your ClickOnce deployment

i download both msi files and copy the files but it not works for me the same error is come any one plz help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question (5 months old at this time) but maybe this will help someone in the future.  I noticed that these errors do not go away for me until I close VS and re-open.  Then if I try to publish again, the errors are refreshed.
If I don't close VS, the errors remain even after coping the files as described above.